# In what kind of situation, c++ destructor will not be called?

Tags: c++, call, destructor

In c++, we love to do something in the destructor.  But in what kind of situation, destructor will not be called?

Examples in the following cases:

1. `exit()` call in the thread
2. unhandled exceptions and exit
3. `TerminateProcess()` (in Windows)
4. warm/cold reboot computer
5. sudden out of power of computer...

Comment: Destructors will still be called when an exception goes unhandled. Trying to enumerate all the reasons your computer might fail catastrophically (from your program's point of view) is futile and not useful information, and you should still continue to use destructors and continue to assuming that they *will* be called anyways.

Comment: @meagar: I believe it is implementation defined if destructors are called for an unhanded exception.  Basically it comes down to: if the process terminates execution, destructors will (obviously) not be called.  The only other time I can think of is caused by a destructor throwing an exception, which almost never happens.  Oh, and dynamic memory.

Comment: Seems he's relying on constructors to release remote resources. Hmm.... maybe you should have the remote resource owner ping your process and release if your process doesn't respond.

Comment: The Large Hadron Collider creating a singularity.

Comment: @TonyTheLion There can't be an ante-diluvian Flood.

Answer (score 9):

This is one case every C++ programmer should know:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class EmbeddedObject {
   private:
      char *pBytes;
   public:
      EmbeddedObject() {
         pBytes = new char[1000];
      }
     ~EmbeddedObject() {
         printf("EmbeddedObject::~EmbeddedObject()\n");
         delete [] pBytes;
      }
};

class Base {
  public:
    ~Base(){
       printf("Base::~Base()\n");
  }
};

class Derived : public Base {
   private:
      EmbeddedObject emb;
   public:
      ~Derived() {
         printf("Derived::~Derived()\n");
      }
};


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  Derived *pd = new Derived();
  // later for some good reason, point to it using Base pointer
  Base* pb = pd;
  delete pb; 
}
```

`~Base()` will be called but `~Derived()` will not. This means the code in `~Derived()` does not execute. It may have to do something important. Also it's `EmbeddedObject`'s destructor should have been automatically called but is not. Therefore, `EmbeddedObject` does not get a chance to free its dynamically allocated  data. This causes a memory leak.

Solution, make destructor in class `Base` `virtual`:

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual ~Base() {
    }   
};
```

Making this one change to the above program means all destructors will be called in this oder: `Derived::~Derived()`, `EmbeddedObject::~EmbeddedObject()`, `Base::~Base()`

Read up on destructors in general. These kinds of problems are more likely to be something of concern to you than the other scenarios you mention. For example in the case of a power down, all bets for safe cleanup are usually off!

In C++ we have good control over enforcing the calling of destructors in the order we want them to happen, which is good news. However in the programs you write there is potential for your objects to be leaked and not deleted at all if you are not carefull enough.

Comment: In this case, it's undefined behavior, but will work in practice.  However, put a `std::string` in  `Derived`, and you have an actual memory leak as well.

Comment: Can you clarify: "undefined behaviour but will work in practice" in which case? The virtual or non virtual destructor.

Comment: The non-virtual is undefined behavior, but I'd imagine it would work in practice, since the `Derived` has a trivial destructor and no members

Comment: The above code is tested on VC++. The Derived dtor is *not* called. This would be a big problem with a class that had code to run in the dtor or object member variables whose dtors would not be called either.

Comment: I never said it would be.  Simply that in this sample code, nothing bad happens (besides UB), since Derived has a trivial destructor and no members.  Your answer is accurate, but I think the point would be clearer if you put a `std::string` in `Derived`.

Comment: Inside the code, there is a comment: `later for some good reason, point to it using Base pointer`. Can anyone show an example of what a good reason is?

Answer (score 3):

Destructors will not be called for objects outside the scope of an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you create an object with a [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10), the destructor for this object won't be called automatically.

Comment: With a regular new also. There isn't anything new about placement new.

Comment: @kbok: In other words, "dynamic objects have manually managed lifetime."

Comment: This is especially dangerous for the rare destructor that throws an exception.  Many containers will leak objects and memory if a contained object's destructor throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Appart from the obvious things mentioned i.e. exit(), kill signal, power failure etc.

There are some very common programming errors that would prevent the destructor being called.

1) A dynamic array of objects is created with 
`object* x = new object[n]`,  but freed with `delete x` instead of `delete[] x;`

2) Instead of calling *delete()* on an object you call *free()* instead.  While memory is usually freed, the destructor will not be called.

3) Suppose you have an object hierarchy that should have declared *virtual destructors* but for some reason wasn't. If one of the subclass instances is cast to a different type in the heirarchy and then deleted, it may not call all the destructors.

Answer (score 0):

Throw an exception in another destructor that's being called because of a thrown exception.

Comment: That simply calls `std::terminate`, which has already been established as not calling the destructors.

Comment: @MooingDuck Ah.  I see you put that in a comment at the same time I posted this answer.  Sorry about that.