# Deleting a derived object via a pointer to its base class

Tags: c++

I have two classes, base_class and derived_class and the following code:

```
base_class *ptr = new derived_class;
delete ptr;
```

Will this code produce a memory leak? If so, how should I deal with it?

Comment: The code won't compile. I would recommend passing it through a compiler first. Better would be: `base_class* ptr = new derived_class();`

Comment: If `base_class` hasn't a virtual destructor this will trigger undefined behavior (§5.3.5/p3)

Comment: Refer item 7 of Effective C++ by Scott Meyers (Declare destructors virtual in polymorphic base classes).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It won't leak the object you are deleting, its memory block will be freed.

If you have not declared the destructor in `base_class` to be virtual then it *will* leak any dynamically allocated objects contained within `derived_class` that rely on the destructor of `derived_class` being called to free them. This is because if the destructor is not virtual, the `derived_class` destructor is not called in this case. It also means that destructors of "embedded objects" within `derived_class` will not automatically be called, a seperate but additional problem, which can lead to further leaks and the non-execution of vital cleanup code.

In short, declare the destructor in `base_class` to be virtual and you can safely use the technique you have presented.

For a coded example, see:

[In what kind of situation, c++ destructor will not be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733894/in-what-kind-of-situation-c-destructor-will-not-be-called/8734224#8734224)